# What should go into /help/on-topic?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I've been dragging my feet on this as much as the rest of us, but we really need to get around to writing our Help Center articles. I last asked about this [over a year ago](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/368/278), and whilst there were some suggestions, <sub>I didn't follow through with them</sub> *ahem*.

Over the next few weeks, we're going to sort out what should be on each Help Center page. If it needs to be changed at a later date, a new question can be opened to discuss specific changes, but we need *something* there to guide new users that isn't buried in 200 pages of Meta.

To start us off, I've put together something using stuff from the following pages:

- [Oded's placeholder on-topic page](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/revisions/1126/1) (link doesn't work; here for completeness)
- [Chenmunka's answer to *What topics can I ask around here?*](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/372/278) (which itself uses some text from the original Area 51 proposal)
- [Chenmunka's other answer to *What topics can I ask around here?*](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/373/278) (unfortunately that section of the Help Center is not editable)

Some ideas for things to add:

- A list of on-topic things and off-topic things (e.g. Colossus v.s. iPhone X)
- Further reading links
- A rule of thumb for guessing whether something's on-topic, and what to do if you're not sure (Hint: Meta)

Comment: I still have no idea how this process is supposed to work.  Having said that, I'll get some sleep and try to do a writeup.

Comment: @Raffzahn That makes two of us, then.

Answer (score 4):

### What topics can I ask about here?

Links for mods: [Source](/posts/634/edit) and [Destination](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/article/edit/957)

---

Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/help/self-answer).

If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

#### How do we define Retrocomputing?

Retrocomputing involves the restoration, preservation, history and maintenance of computer and gaming systems of yesteryear.

Questions are most welcomed on

- how to **use or preserve** computing equipment that is no longer manufactured or supported by the manufacturer. [restoration](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restoration) [maintenance](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) [data-preservation](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-preservation)
- **hardware**, including peripherals, and **software**, including operating systems and applications. [hardware](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) [software](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)
- identifying **specific computers** or **specific games / software**. [identify-this-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer) [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game)
- where and when a picture was taken.
- **computing history** and **persons** with a historic relation to computing. [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)

#### What should I avoid asking?

Since their invention, computers have been used in almost every possible context. It's always a good idea to check first if the answer you want is really about Retrocomputing. As a guideline, it might be advisable to check any question in doubt against the above definition first.

Common areas to avoid are (non exhaustive):

- Questions about modern, currently supported computers are off-topic.  This includes questions about earlier versions of a current machine or OS.
- Questions regarding writing code that emulates retrocomputing features may be better asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com).
- Questions regarding configuration of emulators on a modern computer may be better asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com).
- Questions regarding emulation on specific machines may be better asked on other Stack Exchange sites.  For example: [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), etc.
- Questions about electronics are off-topic unless they are confined to dedicated examples of existing circuitry of an existing and on-topic computer with the intention to understand its workings. For everything else, [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might be a good site.
- Almost all "What If?" or alternate history questions, as they are fictitious in nature and rarely bring genuine insight.

---

What's on-topic and off-topic on Stack Exchange sites is determined by community consensus. This page is a summary of that consensus, but is not exhaustive. For more information, see [the [scope] tag on Retrocomputing Meta](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope).

Comment: If you've updated this and I haven't noticed (I won't notice), please post a comment with @wizzwizz4 in it so I can copy the new version to the Help Center.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of _design_ and _history_ (of such computer systems) questions here, as well.

Comment: @JdeBP Do you want to edit the answer to include those? Then let me know so I can copy it across to the actual `/help/on-topic` page.

Comment: Added to include history questions also. My reasoning is that no other  SE site seems to take care of those questions. Also, there are already questions of this type.

Comment: Thanks; I've updated the help center article. (I've also discovered that the link for mods is broken, which is slightly infuriating.

Comment: Generally, I think that all links to other sites might be directed to the SE-site/help/on-topic pages. That's double service: those looking for that page save on clicks and loads, those jumping into asking are reminded of the help-pages first.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I just added clarification about Electronics and exclusion of fictional questions,restructured the list of positive question identifiers added tag links to each of them to give a hint where to find examples. I stayed short of adding a positive entry for old/new hardware (like _'Combinations of new and old are fine as long as looking for an answer related to the old hardware'_ with tag links for new-hardware-adaptation/old-hardware-adaptation) as I felt that this is a rather complex issue for an easy to read topic page, or should it be added?

Comment: @Raffzahn I think everything should be there, but you make a good point about it needing to be easy to read. Perhaps we can write [meta-tag:faq] posts and then just link to those. (Feel free to make an [meta-tag:faq-proposed] question / answer pair; usually these are Community Wiki.)